# how to get axlsx to write the results of my watir scripts in an excel sheet

Tags: ruby, csv, axlsx

i am using axlsx for the first time and not sure what its capabilities are. I am trying to write my watir results to an excel sheet.I found axlsx to be interesting so i'm trying to use it. I am stuck at a point and not able to move forward.I hope i get help from here,

My scenario is i need a heading for each column in my excel sheet and from the 2nd row my results keep appending in a new row everytime, i have tried the below code so far,

```
     p = Axlsx::Package.new
     p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "firefox") do |sheet|
       sheet.add_row ["url", "projectname", "scenarioname","value","execution time"],:b=>true
       sheet.add_row ["#{$url}","#{dirname}","#{scenario_name}","Pass","#{Time.now}"]
     end
     p.serialize('../../Results'+day+'.xlsx')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to see what your problem is. The second statement appends another row. Can you share a good/bad example xlsx file? Can you be more specific? Do you really mean a new row, or a new worksheet?

Comment: I dont have enough reputation points to add an excel.A new row is appended using the second statement but i want to put the second statement in a loop which keeps on adding new rows in the results file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your process is, so this is rough code. If you need to loop through records, either loop inside `add_worksheet`:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "firefox") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["url", "projectname", "scenarioname","value","execution time"],:b=>true
  run_process = true
  while run_process
    # do something, set run_process = false when done
    sheet.add_row ["#{$url}","#{dirname}","#{scenario_name}","Pass","#{Time.now}"]
  end
end
p.serialize('../../Results'+day+'.xlsx')
```

Or, access the sheet outside:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
sheet = p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "firefox") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["url", "projectname", "scenarioname","value","execution time"],:b=>true
end
while (run process that returns true)
  sheet.add_row ["#{$url}","#{dirname}","#{scenario_name}","Pass","#{Time.now}"]
end
p.serialize('../../Results'+day+'.xlsx')
```

Does that answer your problem?

Comment: Could you please explain what run_process exactly does?

Comment: that would be whatever you are doing that creates the url, dirname, and scenario_name. What process is creating your data?